# Git: Deploy Project Split Across Multiple Folders

Tags: git, codeigniter, server

My website is set up via CodeIgniter. My application index.php file, stylesheets, images, etc. are all located in the webroot, while my actual application - controllers, models, views, configs, etc. - is located above the webroot. Folder structure is below.

```
/var
    /ci_applications
        /my_site
            /views
            /controllers
            /etc...
        /some_other_site
            /views
            /controllers
            /etc...
    /www
        /my_site
            index.php
            /images
            /etc...
        /some_other_site
            index.php
            /images
            /etc...
```

Now let's suppose I want to commit directly to my website via Git (rather than, say, commiting to GitHub and deploying separately). I have already found a method to do that, but I have one final complication to overcome (that may require me to find a new method).

As you can see, a single application  - such as 'my_site' or 'some_other_site' - is comprised of two different file structures in two different locations.

So, herein lies my issue (admittedly, as a bit of a novice when it comes to Git): is there a way to have a single Git project on my local machine, that can be committed and pushed to the server, placing the application back-end in the ci_applications folder, and the front-end in the www folder?

The way that comes to mind very obviously is to treat /var as the root of the project, and ci_applications and www as child folders. However, I worry about Git deleting all the contents of /var aside from the project to be deployed (not sure if this is a valid worry or not). Additionally, as you can see there are TWO projects within the folder structure, and possibly more - that may also cause issues with the Git remote repository.

Am I completely overthinking this? Am I trying to do something that's beyond what Git can accomplish alone? Am I simply an idiotic novice? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using GIT and you want to include the whole file structure then `/var` has to be the root of the project.

To eliminate the worry about whatever structure is currently on the server the easy GIT answer is to push a GIT of it to another repository to stand as a backup. For that matter, if there is a GIT history in place on the "old" siteyou can always revert it after you push in your "new" stucture.

To selectively deploy from the new repository you can always branch it, delete the folders/files you don't want before you push it to the server. Then you can go back to the server repository and switch to main branch. Actually you don't even need the branch. You simply revert to the prior commit (assuming you have one before you started deleting stuff) which would be all pieces and parts of the project.

All things considered, I think it would be easier to clone your "new" repository to a workstation and use ftp or other file tools to put it on the server.